# Yahoo finance API missing data for certain days

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I'm coding a script that fetches information from the Yahoo finance API and even though the API is pretty slow it works for what I'm going to use it for. During testing of the script I found out that I got an IndexOutOfBounds exception and up on investigation I see that Yahoo Finance is returning stock quote information for the stocks I have except that its missing one day for one of the stocks, and I suspect that when using a wider time period it will miss more days as I have got that exception before when using a wider time period, but I thought it was something in my code that I could just fix later.

That the Yahoo finance API is missing entire days of stock quote information makes the API useless for me. Has anyone else experienced this, and is there any solution to it ? I'm guessing I would need to use another way to get the data.

Right now I'm using this python module https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance.

Yahoo finance is the only API I've currently found that contains the information I need and support the stock exchange I need to query data for.

Update:
Yes, I can re-produce the problem. Below is the code to re-produce:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> import yahoo_finance as yf
>>>
>>> quote = yf.Share('GJF.OL')
>>> date_from = str(dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=5))
>>> date_to = str(dt.date.today())
>>> quote_his = quote.get_historical(date_from, date_to)
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(quote_his)
[{'Adj_Close': '156.50',
  'Close': '156.50',
  'Date': '2016-10-14',
  'High': '156.50',
  'Low': '153.10',
  'Open': '153.50',
  'Symbol': 'GJF.OL',
  'Volume': '487600'},
 {'Adj_Close': '153.60',
  'Close': '153.60',
  'Date': '2016-10-13',
  'High': '153.60',
  'Low': '152.50',
  'Open': '153.30',
  'Symbol': 'GJF.OL',
  'Volume': '508800'}]
>>>
```

This code should print out the stock information for Monday (2016-10-17), but it does not. If I choose another stock I get the stock information for Monday in the dictionary as well.

Update 2:
I tried another module named ystockquote and got the same result. I get information for thursday and friday, but not monday. If i ask for a different quote i get info from all three days. When i got to the yahoo finance site it has the stock information from monday in graphs etc.

Update 3:
The data is now found for the GJF.OL which probably would have been related to a delay in the stock prices for the historical tables in the API as pointed out below in an answer. However, I was still able to receive stock price information from other stocks for the dates I did not receive stock price information from for the GJF.OL stock.

While I'm now receiving stock price information for the GJF.OL stock I tried to get the last 165 days of stock price information from the stocks, but there is 1 day missing from the NAS.OL stock meaning the dictionary returned does not contain any data for that day while the other stocks have that information. The stock is NAS.OL and the date is 3rd of August 2016 where the data is missing. Any ideas why this data is missing ?

Comment: Could you give us an example of which days and which stocks? An API link or code snippet to reproduce it would be ideal. If the market was closed for a weekend or holiday, that could explain it.

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer. The API is actually clever enough to not include the weekend days in the dictionary so they are not appearing as empty dictionaries, they are just being skipped from the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

This probably has nothing to do with the Python bindings, and it's entirely Yahoo data. If you read through the bindings, the command that runs is essentially

```
curl -G 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql' \
    --data-urlencode 'env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys' \
    --data-urlencode 'format=json' \
    --data-urlencode 'q=select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "GJF.OL" and startDate = "2016-10-13" and endDate = "2016-10-18"'
```

When I rant it for myself, I got data for 13th, 14th, 17th, and 18th. The table you're accessing is called *historical* data, so it's not unreasonable for there to be a 24-hour for the data to show up.

If you see a discrepancy between that endpoint and the Python bindings, you might be onto something, but the [code](https://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance/blob/master/yahoo_finance/__init__.py) for those bindings is pretty straightforward, and it seems to just pass the date range along.

Comment: Yes I thought about that too that it may be delayed, but when trying a different stock quote I got the price information for the 17th so I could not see how that would be the problem when receiving stock quote information from other stocks on the 17th. That being said, when I'm trying now I do get the stock price information for the 17th and the 18th for that specific quote. I does not really make sense that the API would return price information on the other stocks, but not the GJF.OL quote, so maybe there was some kind of a problem somewhere that has been fixed. Hmm, ok, so its basically YQL

Comment: Still something strange. If I try to get the last 165 days I get 117 days where the market is open, but for one of the quotes 'NAS.OL' I only get 116 days while I get 117 days on the other stocks. After checking its stock information from the 3rd of August 2016 that is missing from the NAS.OL stock. Any ideas on why its missing?

Comment: I got back 2016-08-03 for this date range with the `curl` command: `startDate = "2016-08-01" and endDate = "2016-08-10"`. It feels like a bug on Yahoo's end. Try switching up the range when something is missing; maybe they're caching results by symbol and time range.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I tried just to get 2016-08-03 to 2016-08-03 and 2016-08-02 to 2016-08-04 which gives me data for the other stocks but not for NAS.OL. I could implement a fallback to use the curl command directly, but if that is what the module already is doing then I guess it would not be of any use. Strange that you get the requested results..thats does really sound like a bug like you're suggesting. When I used the curl command and replaced the dates with 2016-08-02 as startDate and 2016-08-03 as endDate I only got data for 2016-08-02. I also tried the dates you typed in but got all except the 3rd

Comment: [I just reproduced your problem entirely with `curl`](https://gist.github.com/ehrmann/5ea6bcda6f3c97c556e28b6baab28e0f), so it's a bug on Yahoo's end. I got nothing for 08-03 - 08-03, one result (the 4th) for 08-03 - 8-04, then one result for 08-03 - 08-03. Repeated requests for 08-03 - 08-04 still just return the 4th. I couldn't find a simple pattern for fixing a single day in a result set. The next time you see this, try requesting n through n+1, then request n through n to backfill the missing data.

Comment: Thank you for your time for looking at my coding problem, since its a bug I'm not sure I should click the right answer although there wont be any right answer when there is not a way to fix it without a workaround I'm assuming you mean the missing day+1 and if thats the case I could not find any easy way without too much coding just to find the missing day as its being skipped and is not an empty dict or anything in the returned dictionary. If I could request n through n to backfill then would not startDate 2016-08-03 endDate 2016-08-03 work without doing that ? Maybe I misunderstood though

Answer (score 0):

Might it be the time zone difference? Try experimenting with different YFINANCE  date ranges. e.g. add an extra day to your end date  etc... There seems to be something odd with the returned data. Also I'm only seeing data from 10 AM and not from 9:30 AM. That's also puzzling.